# Grails (On App Engine) - Basic Search Functionality

Tags: search, grails

What I need is [Search Scaffolding](http://www.grails.org/Search+forms+scaffolding) but in its absence I was wondering if you could point me in the direction of any really simple examples for adding search to a domain.

I can't use the [searchable plugin](http://www.grails.org/Searchable+Plugin) as it conflicts with the [AppEngine](http://www.grails.org/plugin/app-engine) plugin (Unless someone has got this to work?). I just need to be able to filter the scaffold list to contain only the results which match the query. I don't need a pure text box solution, I imagine it too look exactly like the 'create' form except when you submit you get a list of matching objects.

I hope this makes sense, thanks in advance!

Gav

Answer (score 0):

[Google App Engine - Full Text Search](http://gae-text-search.appspot.com/)